# Split string by double dot ".." in java

Tags: java, regex, split

How can I split string by this sequence of characters ".."?

`string.split("\\..")` does not work and neither does `string.split("\\.\\.")`

Comment: Can you provide code/examples to show how `string.split("\\.\\.")` doesn't work.

Comment: The second one should work.

Comment: Yes the second one works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `Pattern` will not work, as you are only escaping the first dot (hence, the second character can be any character, as `.` is a predefined character class for any character).

However, your second example is correct.

For instance:

```
String test = "abc..def";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split("\\.\\.")));
```

**Output**

```
[abc, def]
```